# chai as promised deep property test

Tags: typescript, chai, chai-as-promised

I have a function that inserts into a table and returns a `Promise`. I am testing with `chai-as-promised` that duplicate inserts are rejected. What I want to test is the rejection, and the reason code. When I run the function and log `console.log(err.reason.code)` I get `ER_DUP_ENTRY`. Confirming this is sufficient for my test so I try to assert it as follows:

```
expect(insertTable()).to.eventually.be.rejected.and.eventually.to.have.deep.property('reason',{code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY'}).notify(done);
```

The syntax seems to be correct, according to [chaijs](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep). But I get a failed test:

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (status, reason) } to have deep property 'reason' of { code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY' }, but got [Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'my_dupe' for key 'name_UNIQUE']
```

This seems contradictory of what my console log says the property is.

Comment: could you show the code where the promise is rejected? I understand that the promise is rejected with an `Error` object and you wait `Object` with `reason` property

Answer (score 0):

In a rejection case, `reason` is the object evaluated by `chai-as-promised`. So your assertion must be :

```
return expect(insertTable()).to.eventually.be.rejected.and.have.property("code").equal('ER_DUP_ENTRY');
```

Don't forget to return the promise to wait for the fulfillment of the promise chain

Comment: `reason` is a property I return the error back into. I run into `AssertionError: expected { Object (status, reason) } to have property 'code'` when I try to execute your example.